# Creating static website on gitlab

Tags: gitlab

I tried to follow the instruction on https://gitlab.com/help/user/project/pages/index.md to create a static website on gitlab.  The repo I chose to fork is https://gitlab.com/pages/plain-html.
After forking the repo, I modified readme.md to trigger the build.  After that, I went to settings -> pages to check if the url of gitlab pages was generated.  However, I did not see any gitlab pages url.  I am wondering if I missed anything.

Any help?

Thanks!

PS: I also watched the tutorial video here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TWqh9MtT4Bg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After forking the repo, please make sure that the 'Shared Runners' are enabled in **settings -> CI/CD -> Runners settings**

Enable the Shared Runners and modify some files to trigger the build. You can check the build status in **CI/CD -> Pipelines**

Click on **Running -> Pages** to see the process.

Once the build got passed, you can go to **Settings -> Pages** (Sometimes, it will take some time to show the 'Access pages')

Comment: Finally, the link to the gitlab pages showed up in about an hour after the build passed... it is way too long so I think there was something wrong... :(